# How to ensure that the returned thread ID to thread-pool should not get fetched again

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a code in C on Linux.

In the code, first it generates 50 threads and after that each thread generates 1,2 or 3 more threads.

My problem is (I guess) when one of the threads completes its work (at this situation it may possible that some of the other threads have not started yet), it returns its ID to thread-pool.

Hence when remaining threads starts they may have the same thread ID which the earlier one had returned to thread pool.

I don't want this. I need unique thread ID (by ensuring that returned ID should not get fetched again by remaining threads)

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: And especially what library you are using, OS, and so on...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15723613/694576

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can have unique thread IDs and a thread pool at the same time -- the whole point of a thread pool is that threads will get re-used for more tasks later on, and threads are not able (AFAIK) to change their thread ID after they have been created.

So, your choices are:

(a) stop using the thread-pool, and just spawn a new thread every time you need one (and let the thread exit when its task is done).  This will generally give you fresh thread IDs, but note that the OS will eventually start re-using thread IDs also, if only because there is a finite number of thread IDs available.

or

(b) Modify your program so that it does not expect thread IDs to never be re-used.  If possible, modify your program so that it doesn't look at thread IDs at all.  For example, if you are using the thread ID as an ID for a task that your program needs to complete, replace it with a task ID that you generate by incrementing an atomic (or mutex-protected) counter instead.